# How to optimize code in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I use the following code to get data from two related tables:

```
$arr = [];
$objectModel = new ProductCategory();
$objectModel::$language = 2;

$subcategories = $objectModel::with("translate", "parent")->get();

foreach($subcategories as $key => $item) {
    $arr[$item->translate()->first()->objectId] = $item->translate()->first()->name;
}

array_unshift($arr, 'Select category');
return $arr;
```

In result this part of code I get array with `key => value` to insert this in select list in Blade template.

But I desire to escape a loop:

```
foreach($subcategories as $key => $item) {
    $arr[$item->translate()->first()->objectId] = $item->translate()->first()->name;
}
```

And get clear collection from request. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Laravel `Collections` https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections

```
$arr = ProductCategory::with("translate", "parent")->get()
            ->mapWithKeys(function ($item, $key) {
                return [$item->translate()->first()->objectId => $item->translate()->first()->name];
            })
            ->all();
```

Comment: Why use `collect()` here? The docs says `The results of Eloquent queries are always returned as Collection instances.` See the tip on `Creating Collections`.