# How to improve code Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the following code in Laravel, I get collection from request with a joined table `translate`.

That to get value from joined table I should use additional loop to format array which will be added to select list in blade template :

```
$arr = [];
        $objectModel = new PlacesType();
        $objectModel::$language = 2;

        $subcategories = $objectModel::with("translate")->get();

        foreach($subcategories as $key => $item){
            $arr[$item->translate()->first()->objectId] = $item->translate()->first()->title;
        }

        return $arr;
```

So, how can I improve this code and escape this loop:

```
 foreach($subcategories as $key => $item){
                $arr[$item->translate()->first()->objectId] = $item->translate()->first()->title;
```

Comment: You should edit your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759114/how-to-optimize-code-in-laravel

Comment: Ups sorry, the question might be delete

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly. This is regarded as noise on Stack Overflow. If your question is closed as unanswerable or did not attract responses, then the first thing to do is to *improve the question*; some guidance for this is [given here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Low-quality or unanswerable questions will typically be closed, but can be re-opened if improved or clarified (as appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mapWithKeys` I guess?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-mapwithkeys